# Can't get ARRAYS to work in Office 365 Excel on Mac

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

noob here. Array formulas in Excel just returning #value, even simple ones like `=SUM(A2:A5*B2:B5)`.

Same same if I'm on Office for Mac on MacOS, or Office for Windows on Parallels virtual machine (both current Office 365).  CSE seems to do nothing, nor does Control-U followed either by Enter or CSE.   Can't find any help on this, and wasting lots of time on something seemingly trivial. Any help appreciated! TIA

es

Answer (score 2):

Got it!   After trying every useless random thing posted on the Internet, this worked:

Fn F2, followed by Control-Shift-Return

(NOT Fn F2 Command-Shift-Enter, as suggested elsewhere)

All array functions now working!

Answer (score 0):

For your example I would use sumproduct()

`=sumproduct(A2:A5,B2:B5)`

errors are often caused by not having numbers as numbers, or unequal length ranges.

Entering as an array function is not normally needed, ie the use on Control + Shift then Enter